# how to generate function from a function

Tags: python, functional-programming, spacy, python-decorators

Hi I am writing a lot of function with the following form:

```
def is_match_a(doc):
    pattern = # spaCy patterns
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
    matcher.add("match_a", [pattern])
    matches = matcher(doc)
    if matches:
        return True
```

I want to write a function that generate these function from a given pattern and name. I am thinking something like:

```
def generate_matcher(pattern, name):
    func = some code
    return func
```

so that ultimately, I can do something the following

```
is_match_a = generate_matcher(pattern_a, name_a)
is_match_b = generate_matcher(pattern_b, name_b)
if is_match_a(doc):
    # do something
elif is_match_b(doc):
    # do something else
```

I am new to python and I can not wrap my head around how to go about this. Is this where you use decorator?

Comment: In `is_match_a()` you could just `return matches` as opposed to checking if it is True

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a nested function that uses the `pattern` and `name` parameters of the main function.

```
def generate_matcher(pattern, name):
    def is_match(doc):
        matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
        matcher.add(name, [pattern])
        matches = matcher(doc)
        if matches:
            return True

    return is_match
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this a problem that will merit from using decorator?

Comment: Not really. A decorator is used when you want to add code around some other function, not just to provide parameters to it.